# How do I teleport to a location (LCTN, not CELL) in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know about the `coc` console command to teleport to a cell. When I use the `help` command I sometimes end up with a LCTN name. For example `help Windhelm` gives

```
LCTN: (00018A57) 'Windhelm'
```

Is it possible to teleport to LCTN locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't teleport to LCTN records, but the help command does list CELL records, which you can teleport to using the `coc` command. Alternatively you can teleport to NPCs or other objects in the world using `player.moveto` by looking up their refID.